# drupal search for a specific content type along with its node type for comments

Tags: search, drupal

I have a content type called 'ticket';  its Node type for comments is 'interaction'.

I want a search interface which searches through only these two (ticket,interaction) content-types; and output the node-link/title

Also, even though matches are found in interactions, i should be displaying the respective ticket node-link/title. (since interaction are actually the comments for the ticket node)

Can anybody please help me achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried using views search terms. it searches through the ticket nodes, but not the interactions(comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using the [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module in conjunction with the core search module. You can create a view, filter the content type to ticket, and then add an exposed "Search: Search Terms" filter to your view.

Of course you could also write a quick custom module and do your own query.

Comment: I tried using views search terms. it searches through the ticket nodes, but not the interactions(comments).

Comment: The drupal search module will index nodes and comments. If a comment on a ticket contains "testing123" and you search "testing123" the node that is the parent of that comment will be returned. Are you wanting to display the actual comment along side the ticket?

Comment: When i search for something in the comment, the drupal search module is returning the comment (interaction node-type) instead of the parent node (ticket).
I want the parent node to be returned.

Comment: I have used [Node Comments](https://drupal.org/project/nodecomment) module to make interaction node type act as comments for ticket node type.
And so when I search for something in the comment, actual comment is returned. but I need the parent node to be returned.

Comment: Interesting, so basically your comments are nodes? I'll have to play around with that. You may be able to make a reference to the node comment's parent node in views, and instead of returning the node, return the comment's parent node... I'll take a look when I get some time.

Comment: hey.. your tip of adding reference 'node-comment's parent nid OR self'  did the magic . So now, when I search for something in the comment, its parent node is returned. Thanks to you..!

Comment: Great! I'm glad the node-comments module has views integration :)